# Can differentiation be done in other fields besides $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I was reading some completely unrelated materials where some differentiation was used, but I realized that the discussion was over some field $k$, where $k$ was not specified. So that made me curious:

Is there a notion of differentiation for fields other than $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$? (I know derivatives for $\mathbb R^n$, though I am more interested in for example, the rationals, or finite fields, or other fields, or even more general abstract algebra structures)

For example, over $\mathbb R$, the derivative is usually defined using the limit. But I don't think this definition will make sense over other fields.

Comment: Are you discounting things like formal derivatives?

Comment: You can always do (formal) differentiation on polynomials and power series over any field.

Comment: Probably can do differentiation in $p$-adic fields, as well using limits...

Comment: besides polynomials (where you do formal derivatives), let's say you have a general function from k->k, are there notions of whether the function is differentiable or not?

Comment: There is a mathematical structure called a [differential field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra#Differential_field), which is just a field equipped with a "differentiation operator" (more formally known as a "derivation").

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article on [generalizations of derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative) which might be relevant.

Comment: @Eu Yu: Nice! That was what I was looking for...somehow I have poor Googling skills

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Indeed you can differentiate p-adic functions in complete p-adic fields, but one often requires [strict differentiability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_differentiability) to rule out some pathological behavior.

Comment: There are lots of options depending on what you want to do. If the field $k$ is arbitrary then probably the differentiation was formal: $(\sum a_n x^n)' = \sum na_n x^{n-1}$.

Comment: I have no answer to your question, I also searching answer for the same question.
But my intuition says that if we have field which is complete and oredered (bcoz we have to define concepts similar to convergence, limit for that we need to define norm also). Then we can define differentiation on that field as similar as on real numbers.

Comment: It's not a field (rather, a normed division algebra), but you can do Gateaux differentiation for quaternion-valued functions; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_analysis.

Comment: @Saravanan If you say your field is "complete and ordered" then you don't really have very many options